# How do I store parameters with Angular's ngRoute?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute

I'm using angular ngRoute and have two pages `index.html#/pageone` and `index.html#/pagetwo`. In `pageone` there are a list of folders which are the entrances of `pagetwo`. By clicking one of the folders, `pageone` pass folder name as parameter to `pagetwo`, there is a datatable on `pagetwo`, waiting for the parameter from pageone to display relevant content.

What I've done is fetch the parameter in `pagetwo`'s controller and append query parameters to url so that I can still get parameter when refreshing `pagetwo`. But it seems this is not a right way. If I redirect from `pageone` to `pagetwo` with `name=1`, then click browser's back button, url will change from `index.html#/pagetwo?name=1` to `index.html#/pagetwo`, There's no way to get parameters once I refresh page now. Any solution to store parameters passed from `pageone` in this case?

```
        .when('/pageone', {
            templateUrl: 'pageone.html',
            controller: 'pageoneController',
            reloadOnSearch: false
        })
        .when('/pagetwo', {
            templateUrl: 'pagetwo.html',
            controller: 'pagetwoController',
            reloadOnSearch: false
        })
```

pagetwoController:

```
       if(direct from pageone) {
         $scope.name = someService.getName()
         $location.search('name', $scope.name)
       } else {
        //if reload page
         $scope.name = $location.search().name
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define parameters in your routes using `:` for instance `:id` creates a parameter variable called `id`

```
    .when('/pageone', {
        templateUrl: 'pageone.html',
        controller: 'pageoneController',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .when('/pagetwo/:id', { //add the id param here.
        templateUrl: 'pagetwo.html',
        controller: 'pagetwoController',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
```

your url for pagetwo would then be something  like : `/pagetwo/1`

in your controller on `pagetwo` you can then get the params via the `$routeParams` variable.

See [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) for more information